# How to overwrite custom weight for particular product in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have custom product which is linked to woocommerce products list. I have to add custom weight for that product. I would like to add custom field for particular product in the backend and pull those values in the front end for shipping calculation

For example:
I have template sizes 8*8 = 1KG, 12*12 = 21kg,.... like that i have to add multiple template sizes and i have to show when user selected and 8*8 means the product should pull weight from the backend particular weight. there will not be any additional price for select template sizes

Please advise on this.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  Are you asking how to write a "lookup" array?  What does your code look like?  We need more details from you.

Comment: You should use Variable products (or commercial plugin: product add ons)…